# How to determine which ServiceStack AuthProvider gets used

Tags: authentication, servicestack, api-key

I have written a CustomApiKeyAuthProvider that allows the use of an API key passed in the URL query string as:

> GET https://example.com/resource/42?apikey=abc123etc

It is one of four auth providers that our system has.

Our AppHost config now looks like this:

```
_appHost.Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new AuthUserSession(), 
        new IAuthProvider[] {
            new CustomApiKeyAuthProvider(),
            new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
            new BasicAuthProvider(), 
            new JwtAuthProviderReader(_appHost.AppSettings)
            {
                AuthKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(OurEnvironment.TokenSecret),
            }
    }));
```

Our authenticated service calls are simply marked with:

```
[Authenticate]
```

They can, therefore, be authenticated using any provider.

The problem I'm having is that when I test it by making a request that looks like the one above, it does not try to use the new provider.  I just get 401 Unauthorized.

What is it with the request that determines which provider is used, or does ServiceStack simply work through the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to protect your Services with the `[Authenticate]` attribute.

This requires that only an Authenticated User can access the Service. Users can be Authenticated using **any of the registered Auth Providers**, i.e. it's not specific to the request.

You can find out which Auth Provider the User used to Authenticate from the `AuthProvider` property in their User Session, e.g:

```
var authProviderUsed = base.Request.GetSession().AuthProvider;
```

You can also assert the User needs to be Authenticated with a specific Auth Provider by specifying the [AuthProvider Name](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#auth-provider-routes) in:

```
[Authenticate(Provider="credentials")]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I have reworded my question a little.

Comment: @ChrisWallis Authentication is typically separately from the Request, I.e you normally need to Authenticate first to establish an Authenticated User Session before you can call a protected Service.